# Is Big-Omega distributive to addition?

Tags: performance, math, big-o, complexity-theory, theory

Is the big-omega of a function always equal to the big-omega of all the sub-functions?

Ex:

`F(x) = a(x) + b(x) + c(x)...`

`big-omega(F(x) = big-omega(a(x)) + big-omega(b(x)) + big-omega(c(x))...`

Is this always true?

It is true for something like finding the ith lowest value in an array.

Is it true for every function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

short answer: yes, whenever the number of terms is a fixed constant. If the number of terms is variable however, it gets a bit trickier.

However, for a finite number of terms, it will never be complete after having been written out as:

```
big-omega(a(x)) + big-omega(b(x)) + big-omega(c(x)) ...
```

The reason is because as x becomes arbitrarily large, all but one of the terms will disappear - either due to having the same big-omega complexity or from being subsumed by larger big-omega complexities.

Example:

```
f(x) = x^3 + x^2 + x
big-omega(f(x)) = big-omega(x^3 + x^2 + x) = big-omega(x^3)
```

Now, consider:

```
f(x) = Summation(n = 1..x; n)
```

Here, we know that the expansion of

```
Summation(n = 1..x; n) = x(x+1)/2 = x^2/2 + x/2
```

So,
    big-omega(f(x)) = big-omega(x^2/2) + big-omega(x/2) = big-omega(x^2)

However, using the original formula, consider:

```
big-omega(Summation(n = 1..x; n)) != big-omega(1) + big-omega(2) + ... big-omega(n)
```

Applying big-omega over a sum of terms that is variable can lead to confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the help.